# Overcoming "Display forbidden by X-Frame-Options"

Tags: iframe, frames, x-frame-options

I'm writing a tiny webpage whose purpose is to frame a few other pages, simply to consolidate them into a single browser window for ease of viewing.  A few of the pages I'm trying to frame forbid being framed and throw a "Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options." error in Chrome.  I understand that this is a security limitation (for good reason), and don't have access to change it.

Is there any alternative framing or non-framing method to display pages within a single window that won't get tripped up by the X-Frame-Options header?

Comment: If they're your pages, then remove the frame limiter. Otherwise, respect the page's author's wishes and DON'T FRAME THEM.

Comment: If you are getting this error for a Facebook App and using AJAX calls, i read somewhere that Facebook really likes using # tags for it's ajax contact so try changing links, worked for me.

Comment: Make sure you enable the google maps embed api in addition to places API. Generate you map from here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start

Comment: Also make sure to have 3rd party cookies enabled in your browser. Took me several hours to figure it out, and it solved my problem.

Comment: @MarcB Chrome and Firefox ethically frame non-owned websites in native UI chrome. These programs also allow relaxed same-origin policies to their owners, FWIW. As garen-checkly said, "I'm writing a tiny webpage whose purpose is to frame a few other pages, simply to consolidate them into a single browser window for ease of viewing." That's basically extending the web-browser and would be completely ethical. The stated intent is no different from writing a bash script to open and arrange browser windows.

Comment: Check [Surfly](https://www.surfly.com/blog/surfly-labs-proxy-technology/?utm_source=blogPromo&medium=stackoverflow). It can do exactly what you need.

Comment: Surfly looks nice, but for 20 EUR/month... I think I'll just open another browser window. ;)

Comment: Whatever possible the trik on server side is consider as [*a bug*](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=94836). It has to be aware that for Chrome (and all webkit-based browsers) sooner or later they will no longer support for **XFrame-Options: Allow-From** statements at all. So it just a matter of time, Unless you able to find an alternative way like [Content-Security-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/CSP_policy_directives), I would suggest to change the method of displaying an external content in `iframe` in to an acceptable one.

Comment: @MarcB That's not helpful. OP might not care about the page author's wishes.

Comment: @Chetabahana An Acceptable one? What other alternatives would you suggest?

Comment: @legit-stack Any alternatives that other than frame the external content. For instance use a web proxy, or fetching the content and rewrite it in to a block in pages.

Answer (score 221, accepted):

If a website refuses to be framed, there is no way to overcome that.

(This post previously contained incorrect advice suggesting adding another `X-Frame-Options` header whose value is `GOFORIT`, but in all implementations that would also result in the website refusing to be framed and didn't actually address the question from OP.)

Comment: I had a frame around a website.  On my website, I'm redirecting to Instagram for OAUTH.  Since Instagram sends `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` there is no way to do this inside the frame.  You must use a popup.

Comment: With PHP it's probably better to use the new [`header_remove`](http://php.net/header_remove) function, provided you have it available (>=5.3.0).

Comment: Or you can edit .htaccess if you want to remove X-Frame-Options from an entire directory.  Just add the line: `Header always unset X-Frame-Options`

Comment: I did it and got another error now: Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' header encountered when loading 'https://www.domain.com': 'GOFORIT' is not a recognized directive. The header will be ignored.

Comment: @cawecoy: Well yes, the whole point is that it's invalid. It relies on browsers ignoring the invalid header and ‘failing open’, which is unspecified behaviour and pretty dodgy to rely on. `GOFORIT` (or other random arbitrary invalid token) is deliberately breaking a security measure applied by a server; if you have control of the server yourself (which you should do for any real public service) then the correct thing to do is just set the server not to set the header in the first place.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work any longer in Chrome. Invalid values cause the value to default to DENY.

Comment: Header always unset X-Frame-Options doesn't work.  Apache throws a 500.

Comment: Remove the `X-Frame-Options` header from the page referenced in `iframe src="..."`. For Rails, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445782/how-to-override-x-frame-options-for-a-controller-or-action-in-rails-4

Answer (score 165):

If you are getting this error for a YouTube video, rather than using the full url use the embed url from the share options. It will look like `http://www.youtube.com/embed/eCfDxZxTBW4`

You may also replace `watch?v=` with `embed/` so `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eCfDxZxTBW4` becomes `http://www.youtube.com/embed/eCfDxZxTBW4`

Comment: Oh progress... I wish they would just redirect us to the embed page instead of causing an error to be thrown, and making me rewrite my scripts!

Answer (score 120):

If you are getting this error while trying to embed a Google Map in an `iframe`, you need to add `&output=embed` to the source link.

Comment: That is only true for embedding google maps in an iframe, and not a general "solution".

Comment: I needed to embed a google map in a lightbox, so this "solution" was perfect

Comment: If you're trying to do this with a Twitter web intent, forget about it. Just lost all day trying different lightbox plugins only to find out this "While you can provide links to intents within IFRAMEs and widgets, the resultant pages cannot be loaded in an IFRAME." Source: Twitter website.

Comment: @QLStudio What's the whole point of disabling it in the first place, only to allow it with a different url? I mean click-jackers could simply attach `&output=embed` no?

Comment: @Pacerier Assumably, the view would change to one deemed embeddable.

Comment: This does not work if you are trying to load the iframe src after the rest of the page loads even if you add `&output=embed`

Comment: @Q Studio thanks a lot, worked like a charm for me while loading a Freebase page into iframe.

Comment: @pathfinder This worked for me when I had trouble loading the iframe src after the page had loaded

Comment: This doesn't work for links beginning mapsengine.google.com - e.g. https://mapsengine.google.com/map/edit?mid=zzX-BuFGi82s.kBQeXTGL4SqY&output=embed . Any idea how to make those work?

Comment: As of Summer 2014 Youtube doesn't do things this way anymore, making this answer incorrect

Answer (score 80):

**UPDATE 2019:** You **can** bypass `X-Frame-Options` in an `<iframe>` using just client-side JavaScript and my [**X-Frame-Bypass**](https://github.com/niutech/x-frame-bypass) Web Component. Here is a demo: [Hacker News in an `X-Frame-Bypass`](https://niutech.github.io/x-frame-bypass/). (Tested in Chrome & Firefox.)

Comment: That's an interesting workaround. Works well in FF/Chrome/Opera but doesn't work in IE/Edge though. Anyone who knows something which will?

Comment: This does not work anymore. It gives "Refused to display 'https://news.ycombinator.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'."  _as_  _expected_

Comment: @g.pickardou It works for me in Google Chrome 46, I can see Hacker News in an iframe.

Comment: worked intermittently for me and some Chrome 48. Sometimes I get Refused to display 'https://news.ycombinator.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.

Comment: Ok for Chrome 50 and FF 46.0.1.
Nothing for IE sadly (ofc, the only one I needed it to work with)

Comment: @mark There was a problem with mixed content, try the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dkdnaxaq/1339/embedded/result/).

Comment: @niutech that fiddle works after reloading the page in Chrome 64, but the first time I load the page it doesn't work. (Try in incognito.)

Comment: That is strange... same as @CarlWalsh, in chrome 64, fails on first load (same error as @g.pickardou), but I opened a second time and it now works... Can you explain how this works?

Comment: How come this is not fixed in all major browsers yet? For me, it works with Firefox 61 against both `X-Frame-Options: sameorigin` and `X-Frame-Options: deny`.

Comment: @CarlWalsh try invoking window.reload() on page load, maybe it will help?

Comment: Since YQL is no longer available, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for the workaround. It worked on nearly all the URLs I tried, but a couple of them produced errors. One URL, which worked the normal iframe way, produced a "srcdoc" error with X-Frame-Bypass, but worked later when I tried again. The other URL, which did not work in my old code, produced a "Application rendering error" and a reload button that didn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 22):

Adding a

```
  target='_top'
```

to my link in the facebook tab fixed the issue for me...

Comment: I had the same issue with the Paypal iframe contained in another iframe. It works now! Thanks

Comment: I also added target='_top', but problem with this solution is , the link now opens outside the iframe in new tab without facebook canvas.

Answer (score 21):

If you're getting this error trying to embed Vimeo content, change the src of the iframe, 
from: https://vimeo.com/63534746 
to: http://player.vimeo.com/video/63534746

Comment: this solved my problem, thankyou. what to do with youtube videos??

Answer (score 14):

I had same issue when I tried embed moodle 2 in iframe, solution is `Site administration ► Security ► HTTP security` and check `Allow frame embedding`

Comment: well done for the moodle method, since the other methods fail/get overwritten.

Answer (score 8):

I tried nearly all suggestions. However, the only thing that really solved the issue was:

1. Create an `.htaccess` in the same folder where your PHP file lies.
2. Add this line to the htaccess:

   `Header always unset X-Frame-Options`

Embedding the PHP by an iframe from another domain should work afterwards.

Additionally you could add in the beginning of your PHP file:

```
header('X-Frame-Options: ALLOW');
```

Which was, however, not necessary in my case.

Answer (score 8):

**Solution for loading an external website into an iFrame even tough the x-frame option is set to deny on the external website.**

If you want to load a other website into an iFrame and you get the `Display forbidden by X-Frame-Options”` error then you can actually overcome this by creating a server side proxy script.

The `src` attribute of the iFrame could have an url looking like this: `/proxy.php?url=https://www.example.com/page&key=somekey`

Then proxy.php would look something like:

```
if (isValidRequest()) {
   echo file_get_contents($_GET['url']);
}

function isValidRequest() {
    return $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET' && isset($_GET['key']) && 
    $_GET['key'] === 'somekey';
}
```

This by passes the block, because it is just a GET request that might as wel have been a ordinary browser page visit.

Be aware: You might want to improve the security in this script. Because hackers could start loading in webpages via your proxy script.

Comment: I was doing this a few weeks ago and any relative URLs used in the external page do not function when using echo. (Typically CSS and/or JS, so you might not get full functionality unless you modify URLs before echoing.) Unless I've missed something...,

Comment: Not sure why this happens for you... It should work like a normal HTTP request, just like an end-user would perform when visiting the URL. So the result of the get_file_contents() should be a completely working HTML page.

Comment: Well I may have been missing something in code, but wouldn't a straight echo would be serving up the HTML markup from "your" domain, not the source domain? So relative links would not function correctly. A proper proxy is probably not what I had. I'll try your code.

Comment: How can I implement the same proxy in JavaScript?

Answer (score 7):

This is the solution guys!!

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
    window.top.location.href = 'url';
});
```

The only thing that worked for facebook apps!

Answer (score 7):

It appears that **X-Frame-Options Allow-From https://...** is depreciated and was replaced (and gets ignored) if you use **Content-Security-Policy** header instead.

Here is the full reference: https://content-security-policy.com/

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with mediawiki, this was because the server denied embedding the page into an iframe for security reasons.

I solved it writing

```
$wgEditPageFrameOptions = "SAMEORIGIN";
```

into the mediawiki php config file.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

FWIW:

We had a situation where we needed to kill our `iFrame` when this "breaker" code showed up. So, I used the PHP `function get_headers($url);` to check out the remote URL before showing it in an `iFrame`. For better performance, I cached the results to a file so I was not making a HTTP connection each time.

Answer (score 3):

Not mentioned but can help in some instances:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState !== 4) return;
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
        var doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
        doc.open();
        doc.write(xhr.responseText);
        doc.close();
    }
}
xhr.open('GET', url, true);
xhr.send(null);
```

Answer (score 3):

I was using Tomcat 8.0.30, none of the suggestions worked for me. As we are looking to update the `X-Frame-Options` and set it to `ALLOW`, here is how I configured to allow embed iframes:

- Navigate to Tomcat conf directory, edit the web.xml file
- Add the below filter:

```xml
<filter>
            <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter</filter-class>
                   <init-param>
                           <param-name>hstsEnabled</param-name>
                           <param-value>true</param-value>
                   </init-param>
                   <init-param>
                           <param-name>antiClickJackingEnabled</param-name>
                           <param-value>true</param-value>
                   </init-param>
                   <init-param>
                           <param-name>antiClickJackingOption</param-name>
                           <param-value>ALLOW-FROM</param-value>
                   </init-param>
            <async-supported>true</async-supported>
       </filter>

       <filter-mapping>
                   <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
                   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
                   <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
       </filter-mapping>
```

- Restart Tomcat service
- Access the resources using an iFrame.

Answer (score 2):

The only question that has a bunch of answers. WElcome to the guide i wish i had when i was scrambling for this to make it work at 10:30 at night on the deadline day... FB does some weird things with canvas apps, and well, you've been warned.  If youa re still here and you have a Rails app that will appear behind a Facebook Canvas, then you will need:

**Gemfile:**

```
gem "rack-facebook-signed-request", :git => 'git://github.com/cmer/rack-facebook-signed-request.git'
```

**config/facebook.yml**

```
facebook:
  key: "123123123123"
  secret: "123123123123123123secret12312"
```

**config/application.rb**

```
config.middleware.use Rack::Facebook::SignedRequest, app_id: "123123123123", secret: "123123123123123123secret12312", inject_facebook: false
```

**config/initializers/omniauth.rb**

```
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger
SERVICES = YAML.load(File.open("#{::Rails.root}/config/oauth.yml").read)
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, SERVICES['facebook']['key'], SERVICES['facebook']['secret'], iframe:   true
end
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
before_filter :add_xframe
def add_xframe
  headers['X-Frame-Options'] = 'GOFORIT'
end
```

You need a controller to call from Facebook's canvas settings, i used `/canvas/` and made the route go the main `SiteController` for this app:

```
class SiteController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @user = User.new
  end
  def canvas
    redirect_to '/auth/failure' if request.params['error'] == 'access_denied'
    url = params['code'] ? "/auth/facebook?signed_request=#{params['signed_request']}&state=canvas" : "/login"
    redirect_to url
  end
  def login
  end
end
```

**login.html.erb**

```
<% content_for :javascript do %>
  var oauth_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/';
  oauth_url += '?client_id=471466299609256';
  oauth_url += '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent('https://apps.facebook.com/wellbeingtracker/');
  oauth_url += '&scope=email,status_update,publish_stream';
console.log(oauth_url);
  top.location.href = oauth_url;
<% end %>
```

*Sources*

- The config i think came from omniauth's example.
- The gem file (which is key!!!) came from: [slideshare things i learned...](http://www.slideshare.net/cmercier/things-i-learned-writing-a-facebook-canvas-app)
- This stack question had the whole Xframe angle, so you'll get a blank space, if
  you don't put this header in the app controller.
- And my man @rafmagana wrote this [heroku guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook-ruby), which now you can adopt for rails with this answer and the shoulders of giants in which you walk with.

Answer (score 2):

```html
<form target="_parent" ... />
```

Using Kevin Vella's idea, I tried using the above on the form element made by PayPal's button generator. Worked for me so that Paypal does not open in a new browser window/tab.

**Update**

Here's an example:

Generating a button as of today (01-19-2021), PayPal automatically includes `target="_top"` on the `form` element, but if that doesn't work for your context, try a different `target` value. I suggest `_parent` -- at least that worked when I was using this PayPal button.

See [Form Target Values](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_target.asp) for more info.

```html
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_parent">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="name@email.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
  <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
  <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
  <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
  <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
  <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to work for safari too.

Comment: @jiminikiz can you please provide an example too?

Answer (score 2):

The only real answer, if you don't control the headers on your source you want in your iframe, is to proxy it. Have a server act as a client, receive the source, strip the problematic headers, add CORS if needed, and then ping your own server.

There is one other answer explaining how to write such a proxy. It isn't difficult, but I was sure someone had to have done this before. It was just difficult to find it, for some reason.

I finally did find some sources:

https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/#documentation

^ preferred. If you need rare usage, I think you can just use his heroku app. Otherwise, it's code to run it yourself on your own server. Note sure what the limits are.

whateverorigin.org

^ second choice, but quite old. supposedly newer choice in python: https://github.com/Eiledon/alloworigin

then there's the third choice:

http://anyorigin.com/

Which seems to allow a little free usage, but will put you on a public shame list if you don't pay and use some unspecified amount, which you can only be removed from if you pay the fee...

Answer (score 2):

Site owners use the `X-Frame-Options` response header so that their website cannot be opened in an Iframe. This helps to secure the users against [clickjacking attack](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Clickjacking)

There are a couple of approaches that you can try if you want to disable X-Frame-Options on your own machine.

### Configuration at Server-Side

If you own the server or can work with the site owner then you can ask to set up a configuration to not send the Iframe buster response headers based on certain conditions. Conditions could be an additional request header or a parameter in the URL.

For example - The site owner can add an additional code to not send Iframe buster headers when the site is opened with `?in_debug_mode=true` query param.

### Use Browser extension like Requestly to remove response headers

You can use any browser extension like [Requestly](https://requestly.io) which allows you to modify the request & response headers. Here's a Requestly blog that explains [how to embed sites in Iframe by bypassing Iframe buster headers](https://requestly.io/blog/bypass-iframe-busting-header/).

[image]

### Configure a Pass-through Proxy and remove headers from it

If you need to bypass Iframe buster headers for multiple folks, then you can also configure a pass-through proxy that just removes the frame buster response headers and return back the response. This is however a lot complicated to write, set up. There are some other challenges like authentication etc with the sites opened in Iframe through a proxy but this approach can work for simple sites pretty well.

PS - I have built both solutions and have first-hand experience with both.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how relevant it is, but I built a work-around to this. On my site, I wanted to display link in a modal window that contained an iframe which loads the URL.

What I did is, I linked the click event of the link to this javascript function. All this does is make a request to a PHP file that checks the URL headers for X-FRAME-Options before deciding whether to load the URL within the modal window or to redirect.

Here's the function:

```
  function opentheater(link, title){
        $.get( "url_origin_helper.php?url="+encodeURIComponent(link), function( data ) {
  if(data == "ya"){
      $(".modal-title").html("<h3 style='color:480060;'>"+title+"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<small>"+link+"</small></h3>");
        $("#linkcontent").attr("src", link);
        $("#myModal").modal("show");
  }
  else{
      window.location.href = link;
      //alert(data);
  }
});


        }
```

Here's the PHP file code that checks for it:

```
<?php
$url = rawurldecode($_REQUEST['url']);
$header = get_headers($url, 1);
if(array_key_exists("X-Frame-Options", $header)){
    echo "nein";
}
else{
    echo "ya";
}


?>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue when running a wordpress web site. I tried all sorts of things to fix it and wasn't sure how, ultimately the issue was because I was using DNS forwarding with masking, and the links to external sites were not being addressed properly. i.e. my site was hosted at http://123.456.789/index.html but was masked to run at http://somewebSite.com/index.html. When i entered http://123.456.789/index.html in the browser clicking on those same links resulted in no X-frame-origins issues in the JS console, but running http://somewebSite.com/index.html did. In order to properly mask you must add your host's DNS name servers to your domain service, i.e. godaddy.com should have name servers of example, ns1.digitalocean.com, ns2.digitalocean.com, ns3.digitalocean.com, if you were using digitalocean.com as your hosting service.

Comment: I ended up doing: `remove_action( 'admin_init', 'send_frame_options_header',10);` to bypass this problem...

Answer (score 1):

It's surprising that no one here has ever mentioned `Apache` server's settings (`*.conf` files) or `.htaccess` file itself as being a cause of this error. Search through your `.htaccess` or `Apache` configuration files, making sure that you don't have the following set to `DENY`:

`Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY`

Changing it to `SAMEORIGIN`, makes things work as expected:

`Header always set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN`

Comment: it was mentioned before - see the comment from @Jay on the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6767901/1875965

Comment: I config .conf file Header always set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN!

Comment: But how is this relevant to the question here, where the header comes from *foreign* servers, directly to the *client*, IOW your own server is not even involved? Am I missing something?

Comment: @iliarostovtsev the .htaccess option doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

i had this problem, and resolved it editing **httd.conf**

```
<IfModule headers_module>
    <IfVersion >= 2.4.7 >
        Header always setifempty X-Frame-Options GOFORIT
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion < 2.4.7 >
        Header always merge X-Frame-Options GOFORIT
    </IfVersion>
</IfModule>
```

i changed SAMEORIGIN to GOFORIT
and restarted   server

Answer (score 0):

Edit .htaccess if you want to remove X-Frame-Options from an entire directory.

And add the line: Header always unset X-Frame-Options

[contents from: [Overcoming "Display forbidden by X-Frame-Options"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options])

Answer (score -1):

Use this line given below instead of `header()` function.

```
echo "<script>window.top.location = 'https://apps.facebook.com/yourappnamespace/';</script>";
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this thing, i dont think anyone suggested this in the Topic, this will resolve like 70% of your issue, for some other pages, you have to scrap, i have the full solution but not for public,

ADD below to your iframe

sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms"

Comment: sandboxing reduces privileges, it doesn't add them. see https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/